# How do you generate dual tone frequencies in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm interested in producing a tone frequency at runtime with the frequency and duration being variable parameters. What would be the best way of generating this sound file in MATLAB and have it accessible in the script for use later to be concatenated with other sound files generated in a similar fashion for different frequencies/durations? Thanks in advance for the comments.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sound.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The duration for which a given vector will play depends on the number of elements in the vector and the sampling rate. For example, a 1000-element vector, when played at 1 kHz, will last 1 second. When played at 500 Hz, it will last 2 seconds. Therefore, the first choice you should make is the sampling rate you want to use. To avoid [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), the sampling rate should be [twice as large as the largest frequency component of the signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate#Nyquist_rate_relative_to_sampling). However, you may want to make it even larger than that to avoid attenuation of frequencies close to the sampling rate.

Given a sampling rate of 1 kHz, the following example creates a sound vector of a given duration and tone frequency (using the [LINSPACE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) and [SIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sin.html) functions):

```
Fs = 1000;      %# Samples per second
toneFreq = 50;  %# Tone frequency, in Hertz
nSeconds = 2;   %# Duration of the sound
y = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
```

When played at 1 kHz using the [SOUND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sound.html) function, this vector will generate a 50 Hz tone for 2 seconds:

```
sound(y, Fs);  %# Play sound at sampling rate Fs
```

The vector can then be saved as a wav file using the [WAVWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavwrite.html) function:

```
wavwrite(y, Fs, 8, 'tone_50Hz.wav');  %# Save as an 8-bit, 1 kHz signal
```

The sound vector can later be loaded using the [WAVREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html) function. If you're going to concatenate two sound vectors, you should make sure that they are both designed to use the same sampling rate.

Comment: Do I specify the frequency in the Fs variable? I would like to have a systematic method of figuring out how to generate a particular tone at the same time period though. What would be your recommendations on that?

Comment: @stanigator: I revised the code to make it more general. It computes the sound vector given the sampling frequency, tone frequency, and duration.

Answer (score -1):

<del>gnovice's code appears to be faulty. I think he messed up the linspace-function. You can check that yourself when comparing the same frequency with different sampling frequencies - the sound differs, which it obviously shouldn't.</del>

(I'm stupid. When using Matlab's sound function, make sure to use the same sampling Frequency that you used to generate the tone. Otherwise, you're gonna have a bad time.)

---

Here's a function that wraps up the tone generation functionality.

```
function pureTone ( frequency, duration, amplitude, sampleFreq, save2file )
% Generate pure tones.
% Enter at least 1 argument.
% Defaults are:
%  duration    1 sec
%  amplitude   1 
%  sampleFreq  48000 Hz
%  save2file   no
%--------------------
% If you want to save the tone to a file, provide a name.    

switch nargin  
case 0
    error('Enter a frequency.')
case 1
    duration   = 1;
    amplitude  = 1;
    sampleFreq = 48000;
    save2file  = 0;
case 2
    amplitude  = 1;
    sampleFreq = 48000;
    save2file  = 0;
case 3
    sampleFreq = 48000;
    save2file  = 0;
case 4
    save2file  = 0;
end


t = linspace( 0, duration, duration * sampleFreq );
% http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuston
s = amplitude * sin( 2 * pi * frequency * t );

sound( s, sampleFreq );

if save2file
    wavwrite( s, sampleFreq, 32, save2file);
end

end
```

Comment: The results of your code and my code appear to be identical. I just tested mine with different sampling frequencies for a number of tones and didn't get the error you are seeing. What were the parameters you were using that resulted in an error?