# Android AudioRecord disable gain filter

Tags: android, audio, filter, audiorecord

I'm trying to program a voice detector. By now, I'm able to read audio data using audiorecord, but I obtain a weird frequency response.

I'm reading data as this:

```
private int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int sampleRate = 44100;
private int frameByteSize = 1024;
short[] buffer;

int recBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, recBufSize);
buffer = new short[frameByteSize];

audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, frameByteSize);
```

In order to calibrate, I convert the input audio to the frequency domain using FFT and obtain the maximum value.
Then, I'm creating audio tones in Matlab like in here [How do you generate dual tone frequencies in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452455/how-do-you-generate-tone-frequencies-in-matlab) and I play them. I obtain good readings from 300 to 20000 Hz. Before 300 Hz I don't get good results, just oscillatory values. This makes me think that there is some sort of band filter.

Also, I have been facing with other problem. The frequency response also has a gain in lower frequencys.

I recorded audio with total Silence, with voice and background noise and this are the frequency response.

I get this when I recorded under silence scenario:
[image: Total Silence]

I get this when recorded voice:
[image: voice]

As it can be seen from figures, there is a very small gain like from 1000 to 7000Hz.

My question is if there is a way to avoid or disable possible gains or filters that android has for default.

NOTE: I have trying by changing media recorder to voice recognition (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION) and it has the same behavior.

NOTE: I'm using a NEXUS 7 device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Low Pass Filter or any other smoothing filter to filter out the spikes.