# Playing a varying frequency in Hertz in matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio

I have some matlab code which produces frequency (in hertz) of a sound over 5 seconds. The code as it stands outputs 100 samples per second, and I want to play the 5 second block to see what this sounds like, but I'm having issues with sampling rate and sound / soundsc commands.

My frequency oscillates (data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HoOYEveWHSSE5PMWVvVG9xS1E/edit?usp=sharing) ) and I'd be very grateful if someone could help me convert this data into some kind of real-time approximation of what it should sound like.

[image]

Comment: If you want to play a sound with a frequency of 300 Hz or so, you want the sample rate to be higher than the 100 samples per second you mention. Do you want to generate a sinusoid that has changing frequency?

Comment: I could do that alright; so should I just output far more points in between? This isn't a problem as the generating formula is pretty much just a modified Sin wave but please do let me know how many I should be producing to simulate this!

Comment: Potentially helpful: [How do you generate dual tone frequencies in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452455/52738)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may be helpful

```
Fs=2000; %sample rate, Hz
t=0:1/Fs:5; %time vector
F=298+sin(2*pi*t);  %put your own F here

S=sin(2*pi*F.*t);  %here is the sound vector

%visual check
figure(1);
plot(t,S)
figure(2);
plot(t,F)

%listen
wavplay(S,Fs)
```

This is like FM modulation, but different. If you have an Fold vector with a different sample rate, you can convert it with the command

```
F=interp1(told,Fold,t);  %told and Fold are F at a different sample rate 
%check it
plot(told,Fold,t,F)
```

Comment: Excellent Answer, thanks so much - wavplay is pretty much exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

First, your sampling rate should be at least twice the maximum frequency according the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem.

Next, you need to generate a sinusoid:

```
Signal = sin(2*pi*Phi);
```

where `Phi` is the phase corresponding to the desired frequency pattern, which is simply an integral of the frequency (which you can do numerically or analytically).

Comment: Thanks for this - I should have remembered Shannon sampling and it should have rung alarm bells!